# How to use a toggle button to set the value of a TextBlock using Property Changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I am having trouble setting the value of a TextBlock based on a Boolean expression.

I have this property in my Team class:

```
private Enums.YesOrNo yesOrNoOperator;
public Enums.YesOrNo YesOrNoOperator
{
 get
 {
   return this.yesOrNoOperator;
 }
 set
 {
   this.yesOrNoOperator = value;
   OnPropertyChanged("YesOrNoOperator");
  }
 }


private bool isYesOperator = false;
public bool IsYesOperator
{
  get
  {
    return this.isYesOperator;
  }
  set
  {
    this.isYesOperator = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("IsYesOperator");
   }
 }
```

So this is set to false as default. So, Ideally, I want to display 'Yes' if this property is set to true and 'No' if not.

The problem is, this String configuration will be referenced in another spot and I can't effectively raise a Property Changed event. I am using an ENUM to store the values of the 'YES' or 'NO' values.

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockBaseStyling}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding YesOrNoOperator, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                            <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource ToggleViewSwitch}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding IsToggleVisible, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                            IsChecked="{Binding IsYesOperator, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockBaseStyling}"
                                   Text="{Binding Parent.YesOrNoOperator, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                   Visibility="{Binding IsOperatorVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0"/>
```

So here, both Parent.YesOrNoOperator and YesOrNoOperator are technically the same property.

What I would like is for when you toggle the button, both of these properties are set to 'Yes' or 'No'. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: What happens when you switch the TextBlock with a TextBox. I have learned that Bindings in TextBlocks don't always behave as you want.
If that does solve the update issue, you can attempt to use a restyled TextBox. If that doesn't work, you can try a TextBox and manually update the source binding/trigger.

Comment: Could you show a working example? I’d appreciate it.

Comment: Could you show a little more context in your model? Where is the Parent property coming from?